# Why can I not reset a text field within an IBAction associated with it?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an IBAction called `keyboardResponse` associated with a text field called `myTextFieldIBOutlet` via the "Editting Changed" event handler in the xib:

```
- (IBAction)keyboardResponse:(id)sender
{
    // process this single character - function I wrote else where that works fine.
    [self processSingleCharacter:myTextFieldIBOutlet.text];

    // clear input text
    myTextFieldIBOutlet.text = @"";
}
```

It's supposed to clear the input after the user types something into it.

I get a run time error with this code in iOS Simulator:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7fff0c)
```

Why? I had synthesized the IBOutlet `myTextFieldIBOutlet` already.

Comment: maybe "Why can't I ..." instead of "why can I not ..."?

Answer (score 3):

if myTextFieldIBOutlet is synthesized, you should change the last line to:

```
self.myTextFieldIBOutlet.text = @"";
```

If the textfield you want to clear is the same control that calls this action, you can also use the sender variable you are sending

```
[sender setText:@""];
```

Comment: Thank you, the textfield indeed calls the IBAction via the "Editting Changed" handler, which I specified in my xib file. Both of these forms seem to produce the same error for some reason.

Comment: Huh, that is odd, I just made a simple app with just a text input field and a button and this seemed to work.  I wonder what is missing.